# Excel sheet wont do calculations on Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

Had Office, it uninstalled and I cant re install the disc as I am out of town. Computer repair installed LibreOffice. I am able to open and read my existing documents however the Excel spreadsheet will not calculate. In simplest terms, How do I fix?  Please, can anyone help me with this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check if Data --> Calculate --> Autocalculate is enabled on your spreadsheet.

(This is the menu item under Libreoffice 5.2, it might differ slightly on other versions)

If the above is checked, don't forget to check under options --> Libreoffice Calc --> Formula --> Recalculation on File Load.

Comment: Checked this, it is enabled, still won't calculate. Any other suggestions? Thank you for your input

Comment: @Lindalu711 I know its been a while, but I think your problem was the second part of my answer.